# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt (rhel 6 )

Tags: rhel, compiling, libraries

**System info**

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# uname -r
2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
```

Following errors come when I make busybox on rhel 6:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [busybox_unstripped] Error 1
```

Also I can see the libraries are there in lib:

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# ls  -ld /lib/libcry*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 38380 Sep  7  2010 /lib/libcrypt-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    16 Jan 25 16:48 /lib/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.12.so

[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# ls -ld /usr/bin/ld*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  595192 May  5  2010 /usr/bin/ld
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685416 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3add
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685416 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3del
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685416 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3edit
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685424 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3modify
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685424 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3rename
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1685424 Aug 24  2010 /usr/bin/ldb3search
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    5656 Sep  7  2010 /usr/bin/ldd
```

Why this is happening ?

**Additional Info:**

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# yum install glibc-*
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Package glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-headers-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-utils-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-common-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Also these are the installed packages starting with glib*

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# yum list installed |grep glibc*
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
NetworkManager-glib.x86_64          1:0.8.1-5.el6                      @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
PackageKit-glib.x86_64              0.5.8-13.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
avahi-glib.x86_64                   0.6.25-8.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
dbus-glib.x86_64                    0.86-5.el6                         @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
dbus-glib-devel.x86_64              0.86-5.el6                         @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glib.x86_64                         1:1.2.10-33.el6                    @epel    
glib-devel.x86_64                   1:1.2.10-33.el6                    @epel    
glib2.x86_64                        2.22.5-5.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glib2-devel.x86_64                  2.22.5-5.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glibc.i686                          2.12-1.7.el6                       @server  
glibc.x86_64                        2.12-1.7.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glibc-common.x86_64                 2.12-1.7.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glibc-devel.x86_64                  2.12-1.7.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glibc-headers.x86_64                2.12-1.7.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
glibc-utils.x86_64                  2.12-1.7.el6                       @server  
glibmm24.x86_64                     2.22.1-1.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
poppler-glib.x86_64                 0.12.4-3.el6                       @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
pulseaudio-libs-glib2.x86_64        0.9.21-13.el6                      @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
taglib.x86_64                       1.6.1-1.1.el6                      @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
```

**glibc is installed:**

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# yum list installed glibc
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
Installed Packages
glibc.i686                                              2.12-1.7.el6                                             @server                                                
glibc.x86_64                                            2.12-1.7.el6                                             @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201009221801.x86_64/6.0
```

**Tried RPM**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ivh glibc-static-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-static-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 2ca06d46: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-devel = 2.12-7.2 is needed by glibc-static-2.12-7.2.x86_64
```

**Now here is a chicken and egg problem**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 2ca06d46: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-common = 2.12-7.2 is needed by glibc-2.12-7.2.x86_64
```

Ok then I installed this dependency:

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ivh glibc-common-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.12-7.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 2ca06d46: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc = 2.12-7.2 is needed by glibc-common-2.12-7.2.x86_64
```

i.e when I install glibc-2.12-7.2 , it says I need glibc-common-2.12-7.2
but now when I install glibc-common-2.12-7.2, it says it need glibc-2.12-7.2

How do break this chicken-egg cycle?

**But actually all required glibc are installed**

```
[root@xilinx busybox-1.22.1]# yum install glibc-*
     Package glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-headers-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-utils-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-common-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: As can be seen all glibc are installed and latest versions. So why it I am getting libcrypt error?

Answer (score 4):

Busybox uses static libraries, so you have to install `glibc-static` (which I think is not in the RHEL6, you'll have to find it) in order to use Busybox with librcrypt.a and not the dynamic version.

Comment: yum install glibc-static do not work . so if I search rpm what should be the version ?

Comment: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/glibc-static
Just look at the bottom of this page.

Comment: tired, but failed , see update above, it depends upon some other rpm

Answer (score 3):

This helped me finally to resolve my own `ld -lcrypt` issues. I too validated I had all the libraries in my `/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so` and `libcrypt.a` and these were not found!! (but could see them).

ADDING to my Centos-7 system the static glibc libraries

```
yum install glibc-static
```

resolved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

The versions don't match. You have `2.12-1.7`, but it's looking for `2.12-7.2`. It's subtle, but enough for rpm to freak out.

You can pass `--nodeps` to RPM to force the static package to install. If it doesn't work afterward, just remove the package.

Comment: If I am doing --nodeps , I see lots of 'conflicts'. So what packages should I remove ?

Comment: Shall I remove all 2.12-1.7 glibc? and then re-install 2.12-7.2

Comment: If you can find the 2.12-7.2 glibc versions, sure. Otherwise, just forcing the static package to install should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe caused by the system cannot find file named `libcrypt.so` in your `/lib` directory. It only finds `/lib/libcrypt-2.12.so` and `/lib/libcrypt.so.1`.

A simple way to fix this is to make a symlink named `libcrypt.so` which links to `libcrypt-2.12.so` file in the same directory.

In my case, you can run this command:

`ln -s /lib/libcrypt-2.12.so /lib/libcrypt.so`